# How many ways to specify the shared library search path for a Linux linker&loader?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, ld

I tried to build a project from the source.
[RViz - Github](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz)
And some errors occured when I run the building tool.

```
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libresource_retriever.so: undefined reference to `curl_global_init@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libresource_retriever.so: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt@CURL_OPENSSL_4'
```

Then a post suggests me to remove miniconda version of the shared library at
`/home/{USERNAME}/miniconda/lib/libcurl.so.4`. And then
make s symbolic link to the one `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.6.0` in the same path.

`libcurl.so.4` the one in miniconda library path has comatible issue with the project I was building. So I need to redirect it to a proper one in system path. Problem solved. That's all.

But how could it be? I've read the manual about the order ld.so(8) searching for shared libraries [ld.so.8 manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html):

- Using the directories specified in the DT_RPATH dynamic
  section attribute of the binary

I use `ldd` to figure out the specified shared library the binary requires.

```
ldd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libresource_retriever.so | grep "libcurl"
        libcurl.so.4 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4 (0x00007f254a722000)
```

- Using the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$ /opt/ros/noetic/lib
```

There's not path mentioned about miniconda here.

- From the cache file /etc/ld.so.cache, which contains a
  compiled list of candidate shared objects previously found
  in the augmented library path.

```
$ ls /etc/ld.so.conf.d/
fakeroot-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  ld.wsl.conf  libc.conf  x86_64-linux-gnu.conf  zz_i386-biarch-compat.conf
```

my ld.so configuration directory is pure and there's nothing about miniconda.

Is there anything else I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

> How many ways to specify the shared library search path for a Linux linker&loader

Your question is about the loader, and has nothing to do with the (static) linker.

In addition to `ld.so.conf`, `DT_RUNPATH` of the referencing binary and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, there are also (possibly) `DT_RPATH`s of every binary loaded before the referencing binary. If you want to see what the loader is searching, run your program under `env LD_DEBUG=libs ...` -- this will show all the details.

> `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

That shows the environment present in your shell. When you run under `conda`, it *changes* the environment.

I think you want to run `conda env config vars list` to see which (if any) environment variables it modifies. I would expect `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to be in that list.